# Is .0125% the same as 1.25%?

Tags: percentages

As the simple question states Is .0125% the same as 1.25%?

I wanted to see if it makes sense to write percentage like this?

Comment: Simple answer, no.

Comment: No, they are not the same. 1.25% of $\$100$ is a dollar and twenty five cents. .0125% of $\$100$ is a cent and a quarter of a cent.

Comment: 1.25% is the same as $1.25/100 = 0.0125$. If you are thinking about converting from percent to decimal then you shouldn't add the percent sign to the decimal representation.

Comment: Thank yes that was confusing "1.25/100=0.0125 =0.0125", So I thought they where the same I added a percent sign but that was wrong ok

Answer (score 1):

0.125% is not same as 1.25%

But 0.0125 is obviously same as 1.25%
Notice the percentage sign.

Comment: So the answer to my question is true?, I have to of course add the zero in the beginning like 0.0125

Comment: Your answer is true only if u write 0.0125 without the percentage sign. If u want to add percentage symbol than you would write 1.25%.

Answer (score 0):

They are vastly different. $.0125\%$ is $0.0125\%$, which is $100$ times smaller than $1.25\%$ – the percentage sign indicates a constant multiple of $0.01$. Hence $0.0125=1.25\%$.

Omitting the decimal point, however, is a valid construct. It is not often seen, but may save space.